# How to use PHPMailer and Google's Oauth without install

Tags: php, oauth, phpmailer

I'm using a shared hosting service (so not a single server), so I can't install any plugin onto the server. I just get a mail from gooel to let me know they will stop and disable any username and password to use it anymore.

My old php includes `class.phpmailer.php` and `class.smtp.php` to send mail

Does anyone know an easy way that would let me continue to run my old program without installing PHPMailer composer? I tried to download PHPMailer 6 and look into their PHP, but they just added a lot of php and some of them I don't need it, I just want to use PHPmailer to send email.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer 6 did not change the number of files you need to load - read the readme.

You do not need to run composer *on your server* to use it. Run it locally (which has no restrictions), and then upload the `vendor` folder it generates along with all your other PHP scripts. Managing dependencies without composer is very hard work, so I suggest you don't bother trying to.

Using OAuth is indeed complicated, and that's why it needs extra code.

Comment: Thanks, you mean download from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases? but there have no vendor folder, Thank you

Comment: No, install and run composer *on your local machine*. Use it to install PHPMailer, and it will generate the `vendor` folder for you, which you can then upload to your server